# Mikrotik DHCP client variables for option 82

Tags: dhcp, mikrotik

It is possible to add the DHCP option 82 in DHCP client of mikrotik router?

[mikrotik default DHCP options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyYQM.png)

I want to add the Agent-Circuit-ID and Agent-Remote-ID from DHCP client option of mikrotik router.